# The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter Android studio

Tags: android

I have come upon this error when i try to type this code in android studio, help me please im a newbie

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="polytechnic.temasek.mymusicplayer">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application>
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PlayMusicActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:exported="true"` in the `<activity>` tag in `AndroidManifest` file.

Your configuration be like:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:exported="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:exported="true"` in the `<activity>` tag

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
```